# "sequence of tenses"

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

I am wondering whether it is better to say:

> You would think that I **was** a thief.

or

> You would think that I **am** a thief.

and

> I wouldn't say one **was** more correct than the other

or

> I wouldn't say one **is** more correct than the other

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to say

> You would think that I **was** a thief.
>   *(You probably think (now), I was a thief (in the past and now))*
>
> You would think that I **am** a thief.
>   *(You probably think (now), I currently am a thief (now))*
>
> You would have **thought** that I **was** a thief, but **am** not.
>   *(You might have thought (in the past) that I was a thief (in the past), but I am not (now)*.

And your other examples

> I wouldn't say one **was** more correct than the other
>   *(Both were correct (in the past))*
>
> I wouldn't say one **is** more correct than the other
>   *(Both are correct, both now and in the past)*

Comment: You'd think I was a thief IF you didn't know me better. was a thief can be a conditional.